# Join multiple data sets with weka or RapidMiner

Tags: merge, dataset, weka, sample, rapidminer

I have ten datasets.
I want to merge them together.
Is there a way to merge other than manual data entry? For example, with weka or rapidminer software!

Comment: Can you please translate your title into English.

Answer (score 2):

of course! you can just join them in RapidMiner. Just have a look at the ETL tutorials available at: https://academy.rapidminer.com/courses/rapidminer-datascience-data-prep-foundations

best,
Martin

Comment: In the RapidMiner 9.1, two databases can be merged together and you can not merge all ten to one.
Data has identical features

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for the Union Operator. It allows you to merge two exampleSets to one. Doing it over and over until all 10 of your sets are merged would probably solve your problem.